# React to retrofit call

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java, kotlin

I have an app that has a viewpager with 4 fragments. I want to populate all the fragments with data from my server. I load the data in the activity and I want to distribute it to all the fragments.

So I have this signature:

```
@GET("trashCan")
fun getTrashCans() : Observable<List<TrashCanDto>>
```

And I call the method and populate a List.

```
ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient::class.java)
                .getTrashCans()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : Subscriber<List<TrashCan>>(){
                    override fun onCompleted() {
                        showProgress(false)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        showProgress(false)
                        Toast.makeText(this@TrashCansInfoActivity, "Erro ao carregar informações",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                    override fun onNext(trashCanList: List<TrashCan>) {
                        mTrashCanList = trashCanList
                    }
                })
```

And then I have a method to get a Observable from this list:

```
override fun getObservable(): Observable<TrashCan> {
    return BehaviorSubject.from(mTrashCanList)
}
```

And I get then in my fragments:

```
fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int, hasObservable: HasObservable<TrashCan>) : TrashCansInfoFragment {
            val fragment = TrashCansInfoFragment()
            fragment.setObservable(hasObservable.getObservable())
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
```

Well... this should work, but It doesn't. It happens that the first of my fragments gets empty while the forth have data. (second and third are not supposed to have any data... and they don't)

So I think: When the fragment gets created, the list is still empty, so the Observable in the activity has nothing to provide... But when the view pager get's in the forth fragment, the List is not null anymore, so my screen shows the data.

My problem is: **How do I make the Observable in the activity keep pushing the data into the fragments?** Right now, it only push data when the Observable is subscriped... I want to change this, so it pushes when there is new data.

(I think that the first Observable should comunicate directly with the Subject, bit I'm not sure how to do that...)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `BehaviorSubject.from(mTrashCanList)` - it just takes the current value of the list. It does not react on list updates.

Comment: Thanks for the really fast response. That's the key point of my question... I don't know how to make it react to the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this operation just takes current value of the list and does not react on updates (why should it?):

```
BehaviorSubject.from(mTrashCanList)
```

As one option in your Activity you can subscribe your `BehaviorSubject` to the `Observable`:

```
ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient::class.java)
            .getTrashCans()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(yourSubject)
```

And then return it instead of your Subject:

```
override fun getObservable(): Observable<TrashCan> {
    return yourSubject.asObservable()
}
```

Comment: That looks very good! I didn't know about the share() method. I'll give it a try  tonight and let you know

Comment: I just tried the code. This is still not what I was looking for... Every time as switch the fragments in the view pager, they hit the server again. I would like it to hit just once, or when I press a button, and react to the new values. 
Right now it just hit the server every time it is subscriped... My goal is to get the last values that Retrofit returned, not use Retrofit again.

I believe I need a Subject for this... but not sure witch one

Comment: ReplaySubject, maybe?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I assumed that last data (typically just 1 item, since that is Retrofit) from server needs to be cached

Comment: oh yeah. that makes sense. BehaviorSubject already does that? Because then my comment is irrelevant (sorry I get confused with the subjects or [relays](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/) or whatever)

Comment: BehaviorSubject stores the very last value, yes, but not other values.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the answer. The code quality is so much better now and it works.

Comment: Just one thing: return yourSubject.asObservable() should be replaced for:  return yourSubject...
A Subject is already a Observable

Comment: I prefer adding `asObservable` just to make sure that caller of the method won't be able to cast to Subject again and modify the data. Probably I am just overthinking things :)